# How to get products with its attributes

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns product id and product name.

Example:

| productId | productName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sugar |
| 2 | Rice |

Another table with its attributes.

Example:

| ProductId | qty | unit | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Kg | 40 |
| 1 | 2 | kg | 78 |
| 2 | 500 | g | 30 |

How can I get the product with its attributes to display. I am using React.js for front end.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server.  Please select the appropriate tags

Comment: This seems like just a SQL question. Are you having issues with react or PHP, or just issues constructing query? Have you looked at `join`s? Maybe something like `select t1.productname, t2.unit, t2.price, t2.qty from table1 as t2 join table2 as t2 using(productid)`

Comment: Hello brother, Thanks for your great reply. I have problem with constructing query and retrieving data using PHP and SQL. I want to get data like "products": [ {productName: "sugar", [productAttributes:{ qty: "1", unit:"kg", etc} { qty: "2", unit:"kg", etc}] }] . Product attribute array within products array. if not possible i need any solution to display my product with its attributes.